# How to prove that ways of $n$ of the form $a+bd\ $ equals $\ \varphi(n)?\ $ Where $\ n,\ a,\ b,\ d\ \in \mathbb{Z}^+,\ n > 1,\ d \geq a,\ (a,d)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that ways of $n$ of the form $a+bd\ $ equals $\ \varphi(n)?\ $ Where $\ n,\ a,\ b,\ d\ \in \mathbb{Z}^+,\ n > 1,\ d \geq a,\ (a,d)=1,\ \varphi(n) \ $is Euler's totient function.

Comment: @Elaqqad  Let's take $\ n=5\ $ for an example: $\ \varphi(5)=4\ $ and $\ 5=1+4 \cdot 1=1+2 \cdot 2=2+1 \cdot 3=1+1 \cdot 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the number of ways to write a positive integer $n$ as the sum of twocoprime positive integers $x+y$ is exactly $\varphi(n)$ and we can write:
$$\left|\left\{x,y \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \big/ n=x+y\ \ \gcd(x,y)=1\right\}\right|=\varphi(n)\tag 1$$

Now if we can associate constrct a bijection between the two sets:
$$A=\left\{x,y \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \big/ n=x+y\ \ \gcd(x,y)=1\right\}\\
B=\left\{x,a,d \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \big/ n=xd+a\ \ \gcd(x,a)=1,a<=x\right\} $$
The bijection is the follwing:
$$ f: A\to B\ \ \ (x,y)\to (x, r, q) \tag 2$$
where $x=r+xd$. and from here you have to do the follwing:

- Prove the first statement $(1)$
- Prove that $f$ in $(2)$ is a bijection

and you're done.